# PowerShell Querying Registry and Looking at Null Permissions

Tags: powershell, null, registrykey

I'm working with a local machine as an Administrator. After I remove a program with Windows or a 3rd party tool, there are always registry remnants. I want to query the HKCU and HKLM hives for any keys, values and data left behind. That part is fine. But when I run GCI | Where, somewhere between a half dozen to a few dozen errors result along with the hits. They are all keys that I don't have permission to view, although if I manually go to Regedit it tells me I can still change the permissions. Then I take the GCI results and run Get-ACL to check that I have RegistryRights=FullControl and AccessControlType=Allow to confirm I will be able to delete those keys.

Q1: Is it possible to run GCI with whatever pipes that would "skip" those keys I don't have permissions for?

Q2: If I only want permissions to view those keys so I can check if they meet the search criteria, how do I do that?

I'd like to be able to scan the hives for keys that would return $null as the IdentityReference value for my roles (Administrator, Creator Owner). Possible? Then I would know what keys I need to change permissions on even to just read.

Sample commands:
Get-ChildItem -Path 'Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows' -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.Name -Match '*[search terms]*' }

Get-Acl 'Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows' | select -expand access | Where {$_.identityreference -notcontains "CREATOR OWNER | BUILTIN\Administrators"}

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.